# Python IndexError : string index out of range in substring program

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I am writing a code for a class that wants me to make a code to check the substring in a string using nested loops.

Basically my teacher wants to prove how the function 'in', as in:

`ana in banana` will return True.

The goal of the program is to make a function of 2 parameters,

```
substring(subStr,fullStr)
```

that will print out a sentence saying if subStr is a substring of fullStr, my program is as follows:

```
def substring(subStr,fullStr):
    tracker=""
    for i in (0,(len(fullStr)-1)):
        for j in (0,(len(subStr)-1)):
            if fullStr[i]==subStr[j]:
                tracker=tracker+subStr[j]
                i+=1
            if i==(len(fullStr)-1):
                break
    if tracker==subStr:
        print "Yes",subStr,"is a substring of",fullStr
```

When i called the function in the interpreter 'substring("ana","banana")', it printed out a traceback error on line 5 saying string index out of range:

```
if fullStr[i]==subStr[j]:
```

I'm banging my head trying to find the error. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Put `print i, j` before line 5 and see results.

Comment: dont increment `i` - The for loop is incrementing i for you

Comment: add some `print`s to show you what your program is doing inside the loop, and you'll probably have a better idea what's going on and where it's going wrong.

Comment: I put print i,j before line 5 as furas said, and then I also put away the increment for i as karthikr said. The program ran, and I don't know why the program skipped element number 1 of j and went straight to 2 after checking 0. Thanks for the answers btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few separate issues.

1. You are not reseting `tracker` in every iteration of the outer loop. This means that the leftovers from previous iterations contaminate later iterations.
2. You are not using `range`, and are instead looping over a `tuple` of just the `0` and the length of each string.
3. You are trying to increment the outer counter and skipping checks for the iteration of the outer loop.
4. You are not doing the bounds check correctly before trying to index into the outer string.

Here is a corrected version.

```
def substring(subStr,fullStr):
    for i in range(0,(len(fullStr))):
        tracker=""
        for j in range(0,(len(subStr))):
            if i + j >= len(fullStr):
               break
            if fullStr[i+j]==subStr[j]:
                tracker=tracker+subStr[j]
        if tracker==subStr:
            print "Yes",subStr,"is a substring of",fullStr
            return

substring("ana", "banana")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really helped. I am a beginner programmer, 1st term in college. Sorry if I did stupid mistakes, it's my first time making a stackoverflow account too. Learned a lot here.

Comment: @user3786963, It is not a problem. You did a reasonably good job of describing the problem and showing us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your loops should be

```
for i in xrange(0,(len(fullStr))):
```

for example. i in (0, len(fullStr)-1) will have i take on the value of 0 the first time around, then take on len(fullStr)-1 the second time. I assume by your algorithm you want it to take on the intermediate values as well.

Now as for the error, consider `i` on the very last pass of the for loop. `i` is going to be equal to `len(fullStr)-1`. Now when we execute `i+=1`, `i` is now equal to `len(fullStr)`. This does not fufill the condition of `i==len(fullStr)-1`, so we do not break, we loop, and we crash. It would be better if you either made it `if i>=len(fullStr)-1` or checked for `i==len(fullStr)-1` before your `if fullStr[i]==subStr[j]:` statement.

Lastly, though not related to the question specifically, you do not reset `tracker` each time you stop checking a certain match. You should place `tracker = ""` after the `for i in xrange(0,(len(fullStr))):` line. You also do not check if tracker is correct after looping through the list starting at `i`, nor do you break from the loop when you get a mismatch(instead continuing and possibly picking up more letters that match, but not consecutively.)

Here is a fully corrected version:

```
def substring(subStr,fullStr):
    for i in xrange(0,(len(fullStr))):
        tracker="" #this is going to contain the consecutive matches we find
        for j in xrange(0,(len(subStr))):
            if i==(len(fullStr)): #end of i; no match.
                break
            if fullStr[i]==subStr[j]: #okay, looks promising, check the next letter to see if it is a match,
                tracker=tracker+subStr[j]
                i+=1
            else: #found a mismatch, leave inner loop and check what we have so far.
                break
        if tracker==subStr:
            print "Yes",subStr,"is a substring of",fullStr
            return #we already know it is a substring, so we don't need to check the rest
```